# MKMapView frozen after setting region

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, mkmapview

I have a MKMapView and want to limit the zoom-out-level.
My approach is the following using the regionWillChangeAnimated-Method:

```
    - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated {

    //Maximum zoom-out-level
    MKCoordinateSpan maxSpan;
    maxSpan.latitudeDelta = 0.2;
    maxSpan.longitudeDelta = 0.2;

    if (self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta > maxSpan.latitudeDelta ) {
        CLLocation *location = [self.locationManager location];
        CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
        MKCoordinateRegion region;
        region.center = coordinate;

        region.span = maxSpan;
        [self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
    }
}
```

When I zoom out of the maximum span, the map-region is reset correctly to the maximum.
Unfortunately, after I call setRegion:, the mapView freezes and I can't zoom or interact anymore with the mapView. The app doesn't crash though.

Does anyone know what's wrong in my code? Is there maybe a better way to limit the zoom-out-level?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Solved it. Solution was to use regionDidChangeAnimated instead of the regionWillChangeAnimated delegate method.